# Manipulating the release def ACL from a Visual Studio Web extension

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

Visual Studio 2015 u2, building a Web extension, an action handler for a release definition context menu. I'd like my extension to manipulate the ACL on the def.

Is there a hook in the JavaScript client library for that? The REST API endpoint [exists](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/security/acls), but the [JavaScript API documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk) is woefully incomplete. Specifically, I could not find the list of modules that are available via `VSS.require()`, and that seems to be the proper way to get to REST API wrappers.

EDIT: okay, the module names seems to be listed [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/vsts-api-module-names-john-peters), which is derived from [those sources on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/tree/master/typings). Hardly official, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documentation, but I could find a type definition document at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/master/typings/vss.d.ts . Specifically, if you look for "VSS/Security/RestClient", you'll find the list of methods in the API client. To use it, you can do the following:

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "VSS/Security/RestClient"],
    function (Srv, SecAPI)
    {
         var SecClient = Srv.getCollectionClient(SecAPI.SecurityHttpClient);
         SecClient.queryAccessControlLists(NamespaceId, TokenId).then(function(a)
         {
              //...
         });
    });
```

Namespace ID comes from a querySecurityNamespaces() call, which is currently erroring out on me, but I could make it work from an external REST client (weird!). Not sure where does the TokenId from from. Maybe it's the release def ID.

EDIT: works like a charm with [this monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765983/which-scope-lets-a-tfs-extension-manipulate-acls/45489608#45489608) in place.